# Проблема с получением ответа на POST запрос

Tags: android, post, запрос

Добрый вечер, пишу программу под android, которая должна отправлять POST запрос на сервер, сервер же проводит с полученными данными сервера определенные действия, а после них отправляет ответ на запрос:

```
if ($res_delete ) echo ("User deleted");
```

Но у меня никак не получается поймать и использовать этот ответ в программе.
Мой запрос выглядит так:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://какой-то_сервер.ru/gps_api.php");

try {

    // определяешь элементы массива POST
    List < NameValuePair > nameValuePairs = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > (2);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("n", "3"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // выполняешь POST-запрос
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Скажите, что сюда надо добавить, чтобы в программе можно было использовать 
ответ "User deleted"

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией:

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String responseStr = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

Comment: Все работает, НО
в результате в responseStr сидит не "User deleted",
а код страницы, к которой обращаюсь, плюс что-то еще, вот часть того, что там есть:

    <font face ="arial">
    <a href = "index.php">.........</a>
    .......
    .....
    .....
    ....
    Call Stack:
    0.0198 63384 1.{main}() /home/gps_tracker/html/gps_api.php
    .....

Что делать?

Comment: @bazanski значит не настроен сервер, попробуйте сначала в браузере оттестить ответы.

Comment: оттестил в браузере так http://gps.siteonfly.ru/gleb_test.php?n=3
код страницы такой : echo ("<br/>"."Добро пожаловать на тестовую страницу!"."<br/>"."<br/>");
if(isset($_GET['n']))
{
 $n = $_GET['n'];
 if ($n==3) 
 {
  echo ("<br/>"."Запись обновлена");
 }
}
в итоге на странице вывелось:
Добро пожаловать на тестовую страницу!
Запись обновлена

Я проавильно понял проблема в том что мне в ответ на запрос приходит вся страница + нужный мне ответ?Если да то подскажи как сделать чтобы
сервер только нужную мне строчку возвращал? сервер php 5.3.3

Comment: 1. Отлично, теперь $_GET замените на $_POST.
2. Выводите только то, что нужно, сделайте ветвление если у вас там еще какая-то логика прописана на этой странице. Это уже другая тема, к андроиду отношения не имеет, задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: То есть вы советуете создать страницу где не будет ничего кроме обработки запросов, только ответы на них?

Comment: Угу. API так и работают. запрос-ответ... страницы никто целиком не шлет, чтоб выдать ответ "запись удалена".